# Scala Partial Function Composition

Tags: scala, partial-application

I am trying to compose these two functions:

```
// some case class that just holds data
case class DataMap( ... )

val action(i: Int)(data: DataMap): DataMap = { ... }

val tryFunction: DataMap => Try[DataMap] = Try.apply[DataMap]
val actionFunction: DataMap => DataMap = action(2)

tryFunction compose actionFunction
```

Then I get these errors:

```
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `apply _` or `apply(_)` instead of `apply`.
     val tryFunction = Try.apply[DataMap]
                                ^


Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `action _` or `action(_)` instead of `action`.
     val actionFunction = action(1)
                                ^
```

Can someone explain why this error comes up, and how to avoid it?

Comment: try `... = Try.apply[DataMap](_)` or `... = Try.apply(_: DataMap)`.

Comment: cool, it seems to work for now, but can you explain how this error comes about?

Comment: Hm, I have read a lot of those kinds of answers, but I still don't fully understand it. I'm looking for an explanation of why it is needed in my code specifically. Mine is a concrete example, so that will probably help me understand more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the by-name arguments of `Try.apply`. This here works:

```
import util.Try

case class DataMap()

def action(i: Int)(data: DataMap): DataMap = ???

val tryFunction: DataMap => Try[DataMap] = Try.apply[DataMap](_)
val actionFunction: DataMap => DataMap = action(2)

tryFunction compose actionFunction
```

The `action(2)` does not require eta-expansion, because the `DataMap => DataMap` type ascription forces the compiler to expect a function as return type, so the `action(2)` is converted into `action(2)(_)` automatically.

The `Try.apply[DataMap]` must be eta-converted explicitly, because the input type of `apply[A]` is `=> A` (by-name) instead of just `A`. This is why the compiler refuses to eta-expand the method `apply` automatically: the types do not quite match up. If you eta-convert it explicitly, it becomes equivalent to `(d: DataMap) => Try.apply[DataMap](d)`, so the input type is `DataMap`, not `=> DataMap`.

Note that this would have worked:

```
val tryFunction: (=> DataMap) => Try[DataMap] = Try.apply[DataMap]
```

but it then wouldn't play well with the `compose`.